# how to show saved status on same page where update called in GRAILS

Tags: grails, view, render

New to Grails and this may be simple problem.

I am trying to save some values to database, so I created a simple form with two text fields and a button in GSP (`info.gsp`). When button (update) is pressed it calls method `update()` on the controller & saves the change. Good till here.

And I want to show "saved " on the same gsp (`info.gsp`) with the saved new values. `render` takes me to a new page.

Please help how to do it.

thanks
Sana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the action that is saving your object render the value you want to display for example

```
    def save() {
       println params
       def bookInstance = new Book(params)
       if (!bookInstance.save(flush: true)) {
          render "not saved"
       }
       flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), bookInstance.id])
       render bookInstance.id // "saved!!!!"
}
```

and on your view update a placeholder using its ID. In my example, submitToRemote has a update attribute that will take care of it. Hope this code helps

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <r:require modules="jquery"/>
    <g:javascript library="application" /> 
    <modalbox:modalIncludes />
</head>
<body>
    <g:form name="myform" action='save'>
            book: <input name="name" type="text" />
            <g:submitToRemote action='save' update="updateMe" name="myname"/>
    </g:form>
    <div id="updateMe">
    </div>
</<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you redirect in your controller add something like:

```
flash.message = "I saved something"
```

And then in your GSP, have the following:

```
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
  <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
```

Also note that if you generate the Grails scaffold code, you'll see the exact same thing I just showed you.

Comment: thanks Gregg .my problem is i am using modalbox plugin and this data coming from modal box & want to render "I saved something" to same modal.is that possible?